# How to satisfy type hints when you know the intended type

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

```
class Foo:
    a: Literal[0,1]
    bool_value = random.choice([True, False])
    a = int(bool_value)
```

This throws the following type issue for me (line 4)

> Type "int" cannot be assigned to type "Literal[0, 1]"

Is there a nicer way to do this? I don't want to do

````
a=1 if boolean_value else 0```
````

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. When I drop your class's code in and `from typing import Literal` and `import random` and run this, it spits out `1` or `0` for `a` without error.

Comment: @JNevill Mypy does raise an error for this code.

Comment: I was going to add `mypy` as a tag here. OP, is mypy in the mix? If so please add as a tag.

Comment: See the duplicates above. TL;DR: a static type checker can't trace that `random.choice` + `int` will end in a literal `0` or `1`. You need to explicitly annotate that, e.g. with `typing.cast`.

Comment: `Literal` isn't really intended to be used to define a subtype like this. `mypy` *only* recognizes actual literals, not simply values equal to the specified literal.

Comment: @chepner how would I go about specifying this type of value? Just use int?